# Change colour of the column names of a list view web part

Tags: list-view, master-page, style

Is it possible to change the colour of the column names in a list view web part?  Currently they are the standard 2013 colour and I want to change them.  Can this be done globally via a masterpage or is this a style sheet solution per page....

Comment: If you apply in master page then it will have a global effect.

Comment: Global is fine my company wishes to remove the SharePoint look and use our corporate colours instead.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this in master page. The only downside is it will have a global effect.

Below is the CSS you can try with

```
.ms-vh2 {
     background-color: green;
}
```

You can also look into the option of creating a JSLink and tie it to the ListTypes in question.

Answer (score 0):

Please trace the CSS classes responsible for the look and feel of the list view web part using any browser's developer tool. Override those CSS classes in a custom stylesheet. Then either refer it in the masterpage (to make it effective globally) or refer it in specific contols (web part / app part).